# Can AngularJS ng-Keyup pass in which key was pressed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The documentation for `Angular's` [`ngkeyup`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angKeyup) is virtually non-existant. I have a container div for my view that I want to apply key events to, but I want to control them from a function in my controller.

I'm trying to do something like this:

view:

```
<div class="container" ng-keyup="keyPress(e)"></div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.keyPress = function(e){
   console.log(e); // where 'e' is the keycode of whatever was pressed
}
```

Is this possible at all? I can't find any information, anywhere, on what `ng-keyup` actually does and how to use it! For instance, I want to trigger an event when the `left arrow key (37)` is pressed, how would I achieve this with Angular?

Answer (score 54):

You can do something like, passing `$event` object.

`<div class="container" ng-keypress="keyPress($event)"></div>`

This is mentioned in documentation

> Expression to evaluate upon keyup. (Event object is available as
>   $event and can be interrogated for keyCode, altKey, etc.)

Comment: The example keyPress($event) is good, the documentation didn't show this.

Answer (score 27):

Template:

```
<div class="container" ng-keyup="keyPress($event.keyCode)"></div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.keyPress = function(keyCode){
   console.log(keyCode); 
}
```