# can i paste text input value on-keyup in angular?

Tags: angularjs, textinput

using angularJS 1.5.0-beta2

I'm wondering if its possible to paste the text input value using onkeyup.

for example:

```
<input type="text" id="foo" on-keyup="doit(<text-input-value>)" />
```

so in the doit function i need to paste the value of the text input.

any ideas?

Comment: Have you alredy checked the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup) about ngKeyup?

Comment: Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583496/can-angularjs-ng-keyup-pass-in-which-key-was-pressed) may help you.

Comment: @AndreaM16 of course. unfortunately i'm new to angular, and the only thing i understand is that i can get the key that was pressed and the alt  code. nothing about fetch the actual value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the one key that was pressed then use `String.fromCharCode()` to find which key it is from the event `keyCode`.

```
  $scope.showKey = function(event){
    var pressedKey = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    alert(pressedKey);
  }
```

If you want to get all of the contents of the text input it would be better to use ng-model and ng-change together.

```
  <input type="text" id="foo" ng-model="myInputValue" ng-change="doSomething()"></input>
```

---

```
  var doSomething = function(){
    alert($scope.myInputValue);
  };
```