# Angularjs: how to detect min and max value of input numbers

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to detect the minimum and maximum values of number type input field, so if the user increased the value, an ajax request get send, and so on for the max value.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" min="minNumber"
       max="maxNumber" value="{{value['qty']}}"
       data-product="{{value['id']}}"
       ng-blur="isValid(true)"
       ng-change="isValid(false)"
       ng-model="level.num">
```

```
$scope.minNumber = 1,
$scope.maxNumber = 99,
$scope.addedToCart = false

$scope.isValid = function () {
    if( ($scope.level.num < $scope.maxNumber) || ($scope.level.num > $scope.minNumber && blurMode)) {
        $scope.tooMany = true;
        $scope.level.num = $scope.minNumber;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not pass any parameter to your function from template, and use only ng-blur in your case no need of ng-change unless you want to check for each text change

```
  ng-blur="isValid()"
```

Comment: Oh yea that's did the job, but is there any AngularJS directives to detect whether the Keyup or Keydown pressed ?? i need to separate two ajax requests, so it depends on which key has the user pressed.

Comment: yes you can do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583496/can-angularjs-ng-keyup-pass-in-which-key-was-pressed

Comment: `ng-keyup` is for keyboard, is there any way to check if the user increased the value by pressing on the up arrow or down arrow ?

Comment: you need to use the keycode by getting the user input

Comment: do i need to get the equivalent keycode to check whether up or down has been pressed? it's more comfort to check if he clicked one of the arrows !!

Comment: Please check this link https://pastebin.com/mmAnNaAa , this is a jquery version of what i want to do